# How do I pass a user-agent to panda's pd.read_html()?

Tags: python, urllib2, user-agent, urllib3

some websites automatically decline requests due to lack of user-agent, and it's a hassle using bs4 to scrape many different types of tables.

This issue was resolved before through this code:

```
url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/A/key-statistics?p=A'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(url)
tables = pd.read_html(response.read()
```

However urllib2 has been depreciated and urllib3 doesn't have a build_opener() attribute, and I could not find an equivalent attribute either even though I'm sure it has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_html()` accepts a URL and string, so u can set headers on request, and pandas ll read this resoponse like a text:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/A/key-statistics?p=A'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
tables = pd.read_html(response.text)
print(tables)
```

If u open `read_html()` none of the options accept headers as an argument, so just set headers in request